# A field or property was not found on the selected data source C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have an error on my gridview "**A field or property was not found on the selected data source C#**". I know what this error means but I can't find any problem in my code to this error happen.

[image]

This first image can show the property I want to get, it's the same I have the error.

[image]

This image shows that property **Product.Imagem** exists and has a value.

Comment: May I know, the problem is only for this field(Imagem). Are you getting result if you comment this column code?

Comment: Yes If i put in a boundfiel I get the value from database

Comment: I'm not sure why this is not working but you can use "TemplateField" to achieve same functionality. I can show you if you required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge [DataImageUrlField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagefield.dataimageurlfield?view=netframework-4.7.2) will contain only **value** to bind data. It will not allow object to bind while [BoundField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.datafield?view=netframework-4.7.2) allow this.

Another way you can use,

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Image">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Product.Imagem", "/images/Stock/{0}") %>' runat="server"  />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```